# How should I call each item when two of them have to be compared to each other?

Tags: word-choice

I have two documents which have to be compared to each other. How should I call the first document and how the last? I mean, would it be rightto use names like "documentToCompare" and "documentToCompareTo" respectively? What is the right way to name such things compared to each other? Thank you!

Comment: You are not asking about the naming of variables, are you?

Comment: You'd better ask this at Stack Overflow, I guess..

Comment: @Stephie Gotcha!

Comment: Well in this particular case I am asking about naming vars, but I actually wanted to know how to call everything which is compared to each other in the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you would be fine with a rather simple pair like:

- first & second version
- original & update
- the former & the latter

Depending on what  fits the particular case.

Comment: of course I can use some other names for this particular case, but as there is an employer for each employee, I thought the same apllies to the comparing case =)